Using Koin in Compose Multiplatform targeting iOS
I'm working on a KMP project targeting android, ios and desktop and I'm using koin as DI, all works fine in Android and desktop(windows and macOS) but the build for iOS fails.
some of my dependencies versions:
[versions]
compose = "1.6.5"
compose-plugin = "1.6.2"
kotlin = "1.9.23"
koin = "3.6.0-alpha3"
koin-compose = "3.6.0-wasm-alpha2"

[libraries]
koin-core = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-core", version.ref = "koin" }
koin-compose = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-compose", version.ref = "koin-compose" }

[plugins]
jetbrainsCompose = { id = "org.jetbrains.compose", version.ref = "compose-plugin" }

my build.gradle
commonMain.dependencies {
    implementation(compose.runtime)
    implementation(compose.foundation)
    implementation(compose.material)
    implementation(compose.ui)
    implementation(compose.components.resources)
    implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)

    implementation(libs.koin.core)
    implementation(libs.koin.compose)

    implementation(libs.ktor.client.core)
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
    implementation(libs.ktor.client.content.negotiation)
    implementation(libs.ktor.client.serialization.kotlinx.json)

    implementation("org.jetbrains.androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.8.0-alpha01")

    implementation(libs.coil.compose)
}

my App composable in commonMain
@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    KoinApplication(application = {
        modules(appModule())
    }) {
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
            BaseNavHost(
                navController = navController,
            )
        }
    }
}

and a example of a screen(Note: the HomeViewModel is not a real one, its just a regular class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = koinInject()
) {
//some stuffs
}

running on android and desktop works fine but for iOS fail with this error:
Task :composeApp:compileKotlinIosSimulatorArm64 FAILED
error: Could not find "org.jetbrains.compose.annotation-internal:annotation"

any idea?

I got the same error today, and after doing some research, I solved it by doing these:

Changing io.insert-koin:koin-compose version to 1.2.0-Beta4
implementing co.touchlab:stately-concurrent-collections:2.0.6 as
common dependency as it seems like Koin is pulling an outdated
version or something.

libs.versions.toml file:
[versions]
...
koin = "3.6.0-wasm-alpha2"
koin-compose = "1.2.0-Beta4"

[libraries]
...
koin-android = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-android", version.ref = "koin" }
koin-core = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-core", version.ref = "koin" }
koin-compose = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-compose", version.ref = "koin-compose" }

build.gradle.kts file:
commonMain.dependencies {
       ...
       implementation("co.touchlab:stately-concurrent-collections:2.0.6")
       implementation(libs.koin.core)
       implementation(libs.koin.compose)
}

